# rails helper - how can I get a helper to give me a `<br/>` (or other markup)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My helper works like this:

```
def some_help(in_string)
  in_string + " and more"
end
```

But I want it do to a 
 before the output and I keep getting the < br > characters themselves literally, i.e. not a break but what I want is a < br > that is the problem.

so

```
def some_help(in_string)
  "<br/>" + in_string + " and more"
end
```

doesn't work right.

Comment: Normally you'd want to mention what, specifically, doesn't work.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Use `tag(:br)` instead of `"<br/>"`.

`content_tag(:br)` creates opening and closing `br` tags and using `raw` or `html_safe` is just ugly (not to mention dangerous).

Comment: Why the use of `raw` or `html_safe` is dangerous?

Comment: If you use `raw` and `html_safe` with user input and forget to escape that input, you will be setting yourself up for a XSS attack. `raw("<br/>#{h user_input}")` is ok but `raw("<br/>#{user_input}")` is dangerous. The difference is the `h` method, which is an alias for the method `html_escape`.

Answer (score 2):

you can also use the "content_tag" view helper.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-content_tag

```
def some_help
   content_tag(:br) + "some help"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand you. You add `<br />` in your string, and it stays in plain while you want it to have the effect of a newline ? If it is that, you have to mark your string as html-safe. you do this with `"somestring".html_safe`.

Answer (score 0):

Rails automatically escapes HTML characters. Use `.html_safe` on the string.